# Latexpand and if-clauses

Tags: conditionals, latexpand

I have got an article with several sections. For convenience, I'd like to be able to compile each section separately. The solution that has worked for me has been to use if-clauses. The set up looks as follows:

The parent file for the entire project:

```
%test_parentfile.tex
\documentclass{article}
% Here, I'd load several packages, define macros, etc...

% Define this macro to signal that the entire project is being compiled.
\newcommand*{\projectcompilation}{test}

\begin{document}

% Here, I include the different sections (only a dummy for this illustration).

\input{test_dummysection}

\input{test_dummysection}

\input{test_dummysection}

\end{document}
```

Every section (or the dummy section is this case, looks as follows):

```
%test_dummysection.tex
\ifdefined\projectcompilation
\else
\input{test_header.tex}
\begin{document}
\fi

\section{My Section}

Test

\ifdefined\projectcompilation
\else
\end{document}
\fi
```

Finally, each section includes the following header, which may or may not be accessed.

```
%test_header.tex
\documentclass{article}
% Here, I'd load packages
```

That setup has worked well for me. However, I have been trying to use latexpand to turn the parent file into a single self-contained file. The expansion, however, does not work:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*{\projectcompilation}{test}

\begin{document}



\ifdefined\projectcompilation
\else
\documentclass{article}
 \begin{document}
\fi

\section{My Section}

Test

\ifdefined\projectcompilation
\else
\end{document}
 


\ifdefined\projectcompilation
\else
\documentclass{article}
 \begin{document}
\fi

\section{My Section}

Test

\ifdefined\projectcompilation
\else
\end{document}
 


\ifdefined\projectcompilation
\else
\documentclass{article}
 \begin{document}
\fi

\section{My Section}

Test

\ifdefined\projectcompilation
\else
\end{document}
 
\end{document}
```

The `\fi` is missing after several of the if-clauses. Things work just fine after I manually insert the missing clauses though.

It seems that `latexpand` deletes those `\fi` for no reason. What can I do to either suppress that behavior in latexpand, or how can I change my setup to circumvent that behavior?

Comment: in your original version you must get warnings that the document ends inside the if as you have no effective `\fi` as the document is not read after `\end{document}`

Comment: apart from the missing `\fi` what do you want the expanded document to do?? you have the same `\ifdefined\projectcompilation` test in each case so you will have multiple `\begin{document}` which can not work.

Comment: I want the document to compile, which it does without latexpand, and which it does if I manually insert `\fi` to close all the open if clauses. The if-clause will prevent multiple `\begin{document}` from ever being processed.

Comment: but why use `if` if only one branch will work and the other branch will always give  errors? You could simply delete the code which would be simpler. Your original code will give warnings about the missing `\fi` and when you combine them those warnings become errors.

Comment: I have indicated the file names, for clarity. When I compile the parent file, it just works fine. When I compile `test_dummysection.tex`, I get a file but apparently a warning (?) that `\end` occurred before the if was complete. Latexpand simply should not stop there.

Comment: No it does not work: you have no `\fi` try replacing `\fi` by `HELLO \jgojg kljk`  you will see it works the same way (and you will see why latexexpand ignores everything after `\end{document}`

Comment: So `\end{document}` stops compilation even when there are open blocks? Apparently so. That's horrible.